# PROBLEMAS CON EL HOVER EN CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

Tengo un nav el cual contiene seis etiquetas cuando le haces hover y como que se mueven de lugar como si saltaran se que debe ser un problema de padding pero siempre me pasa este problema[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
<div class="Nav">
                <div class="nav-logo">
                    <a href="/index.html"> <img src="/Img/Tupperware_Brands_Corporation_logo.svg.png" alt="." height="35px" width="210px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li> <a href="#"> Comprar </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Folleto </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Productos </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Recetas </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Capacitacion </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Inicia tu Negocio Independiente </a></li>
                        

                    </ul>
```

```html
<div class="Nav">
                <div class="nav-logo">
                    <a href="/index.html"> <img src="/Img/Tupperware_Brands_Corporation_logo.svg.png" alt="." height="35px" width="210px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li> <a href="#"> Comprar </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Folleto </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Productos </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Recetas </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Capacitacion </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> Inicia tu Negocio Independiente </a></li>
                        

                    </ul>
```

Comment: Por favor provee el CSS mínimo para que pdoamos tener un [mcve], identificar el problema y poder ayudar

Comment: Verifica que si agrega un padding o bien un border, puede que alguno de esos dos sea el problema, de paso visita [ask] y haz el [tour]